# Poor internet speed on ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, internet

I am using Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) for the first time, I installed it along side windows 8 but the internet speed on ubuntu is die too slow, can some help with a hint of how to go about improving the internet speed. not evening opening web pages. I did the installation on  Dell Vostro 1540. thanks in advance

Comment: Please search *Ask Ubuntu* for related questions and possible solutions. Also look at the column to the right of your question in the section titled "Related".

Answer (score 0):

Well it could jut be the ping, in terminal, type
    ping -c 20 192.168.1.1
This will ping your router or modem using an internal IP. If your ping is incredibly high (measured in milliseconds), then your router or modem is having problems talking to Ubuntu. Try talking to a qualified network engineer.